# Safety Power BI, changes to database

Tags: powerbi, nav

I've got a general question, in my company we just switched to a new system (navision) that comes with a free version of Power BI. During the transition I was responsible for the Datamigration. Now that we are live there are some fixed to be made. I used Power BI and Bravo to export a few tables with mistakes. Fix them and import them using RapidStart. Now management is worried about the safety of this process. They are worried that if I write a wrong statement that I can change the database it self. For example that i delete entries or drop a table. I use "Import" as a data Connectivity mode.

My questions are:

1. What are the risks of how I am using Power BI?
2. How large are they?
3. If there are risks, how should I mitigate them?
4. Any other tips, suggestions? I'm quite new to it all.

Regards,

Neuquert

Answer (score 0):

Generally Power BI doesn't change data in your source system.  It's a read-only reporting tool.

Answer (score 0):

While David is correct, you can definitely cause havoc using e.g. native queries against an SQL database if your credentials are scoped with deletion rights.

But outside of these reflections, we have no meaningful answer to your other questions - these are entirely subjective. If you have no idea what you are doing, then obviously the risk is greater than if you are an expert in your field.